# How to get the grouped value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT 
       DATEPART(YEAR, a.spdate) AS 'Year',
       DATEPART(wk,a.spdate) AS 'WeekNo',
       MONTH(a.spdate) As 'Month',
       MIN(DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,a.date), 0)) AS 'WeekDate',
       SUM(COALESCE(a.value,0)) AS 'Value'
    FROM patient a 
    JOIN dp account ON (a.id = d.id)
WHERE 
 a.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM doctor)
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR,a.spdate),MONTH(a.spdate)
```

Comment: Why are you selecting `WeekNo` when you want to sum by month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 SELECT 
   DATEPART(YEAR, a.spdate) AS 'Year',
   MONTH(a.spdate) As 'Month',      
   SUM(COALESCE(a.value,0)) AS 'Value'
FROM patient a 
JOIN dp account ON (a.id = d.id)
WHERE 
 a.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM doctor)
 GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR,a.spdate),MONTH(a.spdate)
```

Comment: Hai ,How to get the month as Jan,Feb instead of 1,2

Comment: Try this  `convert(char(3), a.spdate, 0)`

Comment: Hai,How to Add both the monthname  and month number

Comment: Didn't get can you give me example

Comment: Try this MONTH(a.spdate)+" "+convert(char(3), a.spdate, 0) As 'Month'

Comment: Means I need to add both month name and number then sort by month number

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Jan' to data type int.
I am getting this error with adding both

Comment: Is there any other way to add monthname and no

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33269/discussion-between-kvs-and-aka)

Comment: I will available after 2 hours then we continue